# Powershell ps1 Get Children Copy command basic

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item, ps1

I'm not a coder. I have a Powershell script .ps1 that goes into all subfolders of "db" and deletes the files I want to delete in all of them. It works for what I need. The following code:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\*\dbc\permanent" -Include filmename00.dbc -Recurse | Remove-Item -Verbose

Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\*\dbc\permanent" -Include filename11.dbc -Recurse | Remove-Item -Verbose

Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\*" -Include "filename11.dbc" -Recurse | Remove-Item -Verbose

Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\*\dbc\permanent" -Include filmename22.dbc -Recurse | Remove-Item -Verbose

Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\*\lnc\all" -Include filmename33.lnc -Recurse | Remove-Item -Verbose

Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\*\edt\permanent" -Include filmename44.edt -Recurse | Remove-Item -Verbose
```

Now I want to copy 2 files in the same way in a generic way to simulate this code above but I don't know how to do it.

I'm using this code to copy the files:

```
Copy-Item -Path "File to copy 1.lnc" -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\2220\lnc\all\" -Recurse

Copy-Item -Path "File to copy 2.lnc" -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\2220\lnc\all\" -Recurse

Copy-Item -Path "File to copy 1.lnc" -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\2230\lnc\all\" -Recurse

Copy-Item -Path "File to copy 2.lnc" -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\2230\lnc\all\" -Recurse

Copy-Item -Path "File to copy 1.lnc" -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\2240\lnc\all\" -Recurse

Copy-Item -Path "File to copy 2.lnc" -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\2240\lnc\all\" -Recurse
```

Can someone help me create 2 generic codes (I think one line for each copy) to copy the 2 files inside the "lnc\all" folders to any subfolder existing in the "db" folder?

That is, replace the 6 codes with 2 generic ones, in case there are other folders in the "db" it works too. Thanks.

I'm not a programmer, if possible send me the code in ready format (as an example, thanks)

Comment: From what we can see, the removal of files (the first code snippet) is targeting specific files on each path (with the `-Include` parameter), in that sense, there doesn't seem to be a _generic way_ to automate that part aside from having a lookup table and looping through the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of your code, as explained in comments, there is no automated way to do it aside from having a reference ([hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) in this case) to target the directories and it's specific files. The *keys* of the hash table are the target paths and the *values* are the files to target with the `-Include` parameter:

```
$initialDir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db'
$targets = @{
    '\*' = 'filename11.dbc'
    '\*\dbc\permanent' = 'filmename00.dbc', 'filename11.dbc', 'filmename22.dbc'
    '\*\lnc\all' = 'filmename33.lnc'
    '\*\edt\permanent' = 'filmename44.edt'
}

foreach($key in $targets.PSBase.Keys) {
    $path = Join-Path $initialDir -ChildPath $key
    Get-ChildItem $path -Include $targets[$key] -Recurse |
        Remove-Item -Verbose
}
```

For the second code, it could be automated this way, note that the `-Path` parameter from `Copy-Item` can take an array of paths to copy, in that sense, since we're copying the same 2 files, you can store the paths of both in a variable. Then for the destination path, seems like this should do it:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\*\lnc\all\'
```

First get all the directories in that path, and the for each directory copy the files to them:

```
$filesToCopy = @(
    # Use absolute paths here to be safe
    'File to copy 1.lnc'
    'File to copy 2.lnc'
)
$destination = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Game 2022\data\database\db\*\lnc\all\'

Get-ChildItem $destination -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $filesToCopy -Destination $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Hundreds of people will use it! Do you know if there is any way to hide the code from laymen? Because I had a lot of work to do, currently I use a .bat converted to .exe that runs the .ps1 file inside some subfolders. But it is very easy to find the .ps1 file. To make the .exe I used "Advanced BAT to EXE Converter PRO v2.91". I really wanted to put everything inside the executable, I've tried but always the error. Do you know if it's possible? Then I'll post the files right here on the forum to see if anyone knows.

Comment: @AllanAmaro I have no idea honestly. If the answer was helpful please consider accepting it